# Can I Calculate gltf/glb filesize without Exporting File

Tags: export, gltf

Hi I want to create pdf file which will be describe  geometry, texture sizes in gltf or glb export. how can I do that without exporting any 3d model in blender ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be difficult to predict texture sizes in advance.  glTF requires certain channel mappings (roughness in green, metallic in blue, and several others).  If you've attached monochrome images to the Principled BSDF node for example, the Blender glTF exporter will remap these into newly-generated color images, to be compatible with the glTF specification and the kinds of PBR shaders that typical glTF clients use.

Because of the possibility of newly-encoded images at glTF export time, it may not be easy to calculate all the sizes without actually performing an export.